# Editing text strings in a text file from a batch file

Tags: database, batch-file, text, cmd, edit

I am managing a website for a local sports club. They are using GoDaddy at the moment and until the contract runs out in January I'm stuck with their barely customizable form development. I've set up an online webform registration for the club. Basic input details and yes or no questions which return an email to me like this.

> First_Name : Joe 
>   Last_Name : Bloggs 
>   Date_of_Birth : 10/19/2002 
>   Address : 123 Fake Street, Springfield
>   Email_Address : address@email.com
>   Registration_Type : S14
>   Age : Junior
>   Have_You_Played_Before? : Yes
>   If_\'Yes\'_Where? : Earth
>   _Year_Played : Winter 2014
>   Preferred_Player_Position_1 : GA
>   Preferred_Player_Position_2 : GS
>   Preferred_Player_Position_3 : WA

As you can see the output is bulky and editing the tooltip text to make it shorter is a no go as I tried that and had some internal error with their webdesigner which they didn't care to rectify so had to delete and start again for most of my form. So I want to create a batch file to edit out the bulk into smaller codes to eventually port over to a database manager (off topic - but suggestions welcome on that one) that can produce team sheets based on age etc.

Comment: In one sentence what do you want to do ?

Comment: I want to create a batch file to edit out the bulk into smaller codes eg: replace Date_of_Birth with DOB, Last_Name with LN etc

Comment: Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir

Comment: I've got a part solution using http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeBatchFiles.php#Batch.FindAndReplace

How do I write that output to the file?

Comment: I've just added this answer which may be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir/24887951#24887951

Comment: Thank you foxidrive - Using Repl from your answer I can write to file quite easy. In your answer to that, you suggested using a batch file for multiple changes. Could you assist me in doing so? As an example "First_Name" will be "PIFN", "Last_Name" will be "PILN"